# How can I use more CPU power to speed up builds with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I've got a slow build taking around 40 seconds, which is the min problem. The hardware is good and the disk are fast. I've noticed that only one thread is in use.

Is there a way similar to `make -j 6` that will help performance?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'd (carefully) say this is not possible for a very simple reason:

Browserify runs on top of node, which as I'm sure you know, is a JavaScript engine itself. JavaScript is ***single threaded***, so no matter what, you won't be able to use multithreading when the technology is based on that.</strike>

The only way I see this to become possible is if the build tool is rewritten using a different technology, and I don't see that happening.

After considering the comments, I googled!

Turns out, there is a project that attempts to do just that: [paq](https://github.com/ben-ng/paq).
I (obviously) have no experience using it, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not correct. A single instance of node is single threaded. But I have written multi threaded node applications. I have easily spawned worker nodes from one process. It's simple.

Comment: (the clue is in the name) :-)

Comment: Also, it is not a JavaScript engine in any way whatsoever.

Comment: what is ("*not a javascript engine in any way*")? (BTW, I'm sold... :) it *can* be made multithreaded)

Comment: It's snazzy socket server and other utils with a Javascript accessible API. V8 is the engine.

Comment: You my friend may take one cigar of your choice the box marked "expensive".

Comment: :-) Happy to have helped. Regarding engine or not, that's a bit of a nitpicking. Quote from nodejs.org: *Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.* - so it a "*runtime*", not an "*engine*".

Comment: Turns out though, paq is Mac only, is stale and is written in Objective-C. Pretty poor choice if you ask me as Browserify often needs to run in build scripts on servers.

Comment: I guess that shows the kind of solution your looking for though.. a re-implementation of browserify.